# Abrir un PDF desde un ListBox en C#

Tags: c#, pdf, listbox

Intento abrir un documento en formato PDF desde un `ListBox` con C#. Logro cargar los documento que están en el archivo pero no se visualiza en el `axAcroPDF1`, lo que quiero es poder cargar todos los archivos a este `ListBox` y poder seleccionar el que quiera y que se me muestre en el `axAcroPDF1`. Gracias Adelantadas!!!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog();

            if (FBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

            {
                FileName.Items.Clear();
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FBD.SelectedPath);
                string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(FBD.SelectedPath);

                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    FileName.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
                }
                foreach (string dir in dirs)
                {
                    FileName.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName((dir)));
                }
            }

        }


        private void FileName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileInfo file = (FileInfo)FileName.SelectedItem;
            Process.Start(file.FullName);
        }

        private void axAcroPDF1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes llamar al ejecutable de Acrobat Reader

```
    var p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.Arguments= @"C:\Temp\tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\ElPDF.pdf";
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";
    p.Start();
```